# how to create a foreign-key relationship without holding a reference to the father entity in fluent NHibernate

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I can't create a foreign-key relation ship with this setup. Please help!
I have 3 classes:

```
Class Father
{
    Public Guid Id //This is the PK but I DON'T want to use this
    Public GuidWrapper myRealId //I need to use this unique id for the relation ship
}
Class Child
{
    Public Guid Id //not relevant. just to clarify this it the PK
    Public GuidWrapper dadId //I need to use this unique id for the relation ship
}
Class GuidWrapper
{
    Public Guid guid
}
```

also I have these relevant columns for the Father and Child tables:

```
Father table:
 column: myRealIdIdentifier uniqueidentifier
Child table:
 column: dadIdIdentifier uniqueidentifier
```

What I'm trying to do in fluent Nhibernate (using automappings, but I can do overrides) is create a foreign-key relation ship with cascade delete enabled where the child points at the father's myRealId which isn't the PK.

Notice the child DOES NOT have a reference to the father, I rather need to use the GuidWrapper as the foreign key property. Also notice that the underlying column names are not the same as the properties.

I tried various variations of this but to no avail because I'm new to Nhibernate:

```
childAutoMapping.References<Father>(x => x.dadId).Column("dadIdIdentifier")
                        .PropertyRef("myRealId");
```

Any help would be greatly appreicated!

Comment: Why do you need to use GuidWrapper? I mean, why not reference by GUID's directly?

Comment: it's not my choice. It's company code

Comment: OK, but what kind of control do you have over Child / father code? Can you subclass those and use some better constructs? Can you add more properties. Cause nhibernate requirs all methods to be virtual, and yours aren't...